# Do you have to use a four gigabyte graphic processing unit to mine in 2021?

Tags: gpu

The reason why I'm asking is because i own a ASUS GeForce GTX 660 Ti 967Mhz PCI-E 3.0 2048Mb 6008Mhz 192 bit gpu and I've googled how to mine with it in 2021 but haven't found anything solid as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to use an ASIC to mine Bitcoin in 2021. A graphics card of any kind won't work.

Comment: fag liar shut up